# Suppose $\|x_n\|\leq 1$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $x_n\to x$ weakly as $n\to\infty$. Is it true that $\|x\|\leq 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $\mathcal H$ (an infinite dimensional Hilbert space with associated norm $\|\cdot\|$) and  $x\in \mathcal H.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the norm is (sequentially) weakly lower-semicontinuous: if $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$, then $||x|| \le \liminf_n ||x_n||$.

[Weak lower semicontinuity of a functional on Hilbert space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87634/weak-lower-semicontinuity-of-a-functional-on-hilbert-space)

The proof is here.